# Passing an Object to a controller using BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view and I'm trying to pass the input from a textbox upon a button click to an action using BeginForm. My code keeps passing a null object to the action method in the controller. How do I pass the object to the controller via the form ?

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetQueueInfoWorkorder","Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.ID);
    <input type="Submit" value ="Search" class="ui-button-icon-secondary"/>
}
```

Here is the actionmethod :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetQueueInfoWorkorder(UserResponse id)
{
    //Check queue complete
    int woNumber = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    tb_QueueCompleted completed = db.tb_QueueCompleted.SingleOrDefault(x => x.WorkOrderNumber == woNumber);
    if (completed != null)
    {
        var u = new UserResponse { ID = completed.QueueId.ToString() };
        GetLogInfoCompleted(u);
        return View("GetLogInfo");
    }

    //check queue pending

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Share controller's action method, please. What's more, you shouldn't do sth like `id = Model` in routes. Model values will be automatically bound from form values (f.e. from text box). Your action should take only one argument - which should be type of `Model`.

Comment: Underneath the scenes, the property names have to match up between the strongly typed model and the model used at the action's parameter. It may help to post how the resulting `<input>` element is currently being rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're fairly close, but make these changes & it should work as expected:

Model:

```
public class UserResponse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model UserResponse
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetQueueInfoWorkorder", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID);
    <input type="Submit" value ="Search" class="ui-button-icon-secondary"/>
}
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult GetQueueInfoWorkorder(UserResponse model)
{
     int woNumber = model.ID;
     //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. So I assume the routing requires model to be used as a parameter if I want the object to be passed ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you - routing is not really interested in the model at all. The model is posted from a form and the action parameter (UserResponse) takes care of the binding.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to understand why (UserResponse model) worked in my action method and not (UserResponse id)

Comment: (UserResponse id) didn't work because of the way you were trying to access the ID value. In this case `id` was the POSTed model, so to get the ID you should have used `int woNumber = id.ID'. You can see that id was not a good name for the model parameter!

Answer (score 1):

if the @model of your view is UserResponse , then on submission of this page the model (UserResponse) will automatically get submitted to the controller. Where have you declared the @model for the view.